# is it possible to send custom variables to Google analytics while using ecommerce extension

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

So basicly i'm trying to get custom variables trough to google analytics panel while using ecommerce extension. My main goal is to give every item a set of custom values.

My "code" looks like this:

```
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': 'id',                     
    'affiliation': 'affiliation',  
});
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': 'id',
    'name': 'Loan  - name',
    'sku': '{RIDA:success_loan_id}',
    'loanSumEur': 'Sum',
    'loanSumLit': 'Sum LTL',
    'loanLength': 'length',
    'loanData': 'data'
});
ga('ecommerce:send');
ga('ecommerce:clear');
```

How should I declare those loanSumEur, loanSumLit, loanlength, loanData variables so Google would pass them trough to the google analytics admin panel. Is it even possible ?

It's quite easy to declare custom variables for site tracking, however I got a little bit stuck trying to do the same thing on transaction items.

BR's

Comment: As far as I know only hit types which support custom dimensions/metrics are: pageview, event, timing or social. Ecommerce module does not allow you to add extra variables not previously defined by Google. But maybe there is some walkaround using standard events + custom dimensions/metrics. What exactly you would like to achieve? What kind of report/analysis you would like to do?

Comment: I'm just trying to pass through extra data with the "product" so whoever uses the ecommerce analysis gets to see more about a "product" then just it's ID from the website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using custom dimensions & metrics.

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Powerup',                // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Extras',             // Product category (string).
  'variant': 'red',                 // Product variant (string).
  'price': '10.00',                 // Product price (currency).
  'quantity': 2,                    // Product quantity (number).
  'dimension4': 'strong',           // Product-scoped custom dimension (string).
  'metric2': 5                      // Product-scoped custom metric (integer).
});
ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {
  'id': 'T12345',
  'revenue': '20.00'
});

ga('send', 'pageview');     // Send transaction data with initial pageview.
```

See : [Custom Dimensions & Metrics - Product-level scope](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/platform/customdimsmets#example-product)

Comment: Is it Enchanced Ecommerce module?

Comment: Yes it is Enhanced ecommerce.

Comment: This works with non-enhanced ecommerce, but you can't use product scoped dimensions as these are enhanced only.