# Add custom metric to google analytics transaction

Tags: google-analytics, transactions

Im trying to add custom metrics to transactions on google analytics. It must be per transaction. Currently I'm adding transactions like this.

```
    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
        'id':           '',
        'affiliation':  '',
        'revenue':      '',
        'tax':          '',
        'currency':     ''
    });
    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
        'id':       '',
        'name':     '',
        'sku':      '',
        'category': '',
        'price':    '',
        'currency': '',
        'quantity': ''
    });
```

Now what I was thinking was adding the following to the transaction but don't quite know if its the right way to do it.

```
ga('ecommerce:addProduct', {'metric1': hasTransacted});
```

I know with page views custom metrics can be added to page view like this

```
ga('set', 'metric1', '1');

ga('send', 'pageview');
```

But Im trying to add it to a transaction instead.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the metric to the transaction hit, just like in your example with addProduct. Here is a similar question asked here  [is it possible to send custom variables to Google analytics while using ecommerce extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27821900/is-it-possible-to-send-custom-variables-to-google-analytics-while-using-ecommerc).